# API V2 - Enterprise - Create Managed User

Tags: box-api

I am evaluating box for enterprise accounts.  Within version 1 docs there are Enterprise Commands such as

- create_managed_user
- edit_managed_user
  etc

Is there V2 commands which are the same ?
Will the existing V1 Commands for these methods be deprecated ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The V2 API has some admin-level APIs, mostly under the /users endpoint (http://developers.box.com/docs/).  However, many methods are still being added to the V2 API, and much of the administrative functionality is only available in the V1 API at the moment.  The V2 API does not yet have equivalent method's for create_managed_user or edit_managed_user from V1.

We generally recommend that apps use the V2 API as much as possible, and include V1 calls when needed.  As we add more methods to the V2 API, it's best to change your v1 calls as soon as you can.

Comment: Check the date on this post.  It is pre V2 being released as production.

Answer (score 1):

Updating this, since someone recently referred to it, even though this answer is pretty ancient.

Fully updated: 
There is about 20% more surface area available for "Administrative use" in the V2 API, than there was in the V1 Box.com API.

Where?  /users

1. POST to create a new one
2. GET /users to see all the users in the enterprise
3. PUT /users/ to update a specific user
4. GET /users/?fields=a,b,c to get specific fields you want to see, including some non default fields like their enterprise-id, their role, some permissions, etc.  [See the docs](https://developers.box.com/docs/#users) for users, and look for the green fields.

Where else?  /groups

1. POST to create a new one
2. GET to get a list of all groups
3. GET /groups//memberships to get a list of all the users in a group

What else?  as-user headers can let you build applications that automate processes for your users.

Of course to do all these things, you have to be an admin, granted the permissions to do these various different things.