# create user Account in PHP Using Box.net API

Tags: php, curl, box-api, box

I want to create user Account in PHP, i searched almost all of stackoverflow at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/box-api as well as Box API but cannot find anything

Cannot find any documentation of "create_managed_user" function in V2

Comment: do you know that their API supports this?

Comment: @Dagon i cant find anything to user accounts

Comment: well then, i may simply not exist.

Comment: Are you talking about `Box.com` API?

Comment: see this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316943/api-v2-enterprise-create-managed-user

Comment: @RahilWazir Yes Box.com API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Box v2 API allows you to [create managed (enterprise) users](https://developers.box.com/docs/#users-create-an-enterprise-user) if and only if you are a Box enterprise administrator:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
-d '{"login": "eddard@box.com", "name": "Ned Stark"}'
-X POST
```